# What is the difference between automated and rule based systems

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I would like to understand that in the context of Artificial intelligence, is there anything called as rule based ai or is it just equal to any automated system. When i read about rule based ai it sounded nothing different from automated systems. If rule based ai is same as automated system , can it be concluded that every automated system is a kind of rule based ai ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Automated*** describes systems which operate without manual intervention in general.

***Rule-based*** describes a particular architecture of automated systems where behavior is specified in terms of *if-then* rules, also known as *productions*.

Comment: Simple :-) Thanks :-)